# Java Google Drive API shared drive access

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I need to write a JAVA program that reads content in a Google Drive to import it in another application. I'm trying to access a drive shared with a service account I created and when trying to request the shared drive by its id, I've got a 404 not found error.

Here are the steps I did :

- I added the "Google Drive API" service to the project in GCP.
- I created the service account I want to use.
- I created a key.
  The key is like that :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxx",
  "client_email": "api-drive-access@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/api-drive-access%40xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

- I created a Windows system environment variable named GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and pointing on the key json file.
- I shared the drive I want to access to the service account email
- I wrote this code :

```
final GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
                .getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer).setApplicationName("Drive samples").build();

        final List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

        final OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String pageToken = null;
        do {
            final FileList result = service
                    .files()
                    .list()
                    .setCorpora("drive")
                    .setQ("mimeType='image/jpeg'")
                    .setDriveId("xxxxxxx")
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, title)")
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .setSupportsAllDrives(Boolean.TRUE)
                    .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(Boolean.TRUE)
                    .execute();
            for (final File file : result.getFiles()) {
                System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }

            files.addAll(result.getFiles());

            pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
        } while (pageToken != null);
```

The service.execute() method returns a 404 not found error.

Do someone see something wrong in my call or my conf that explains this error ?

Thanks,

Mathieu